# Differentiating $\ln(4x)$.

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Why is the derivative of $\ln(4x)$ equal to: $\frac{1}{x}$ Shouldn't it be? $$\frac{1}{4x}$$ This seems so wrong to me because the derivative of $\ln x$ is $\tfrac{1}{x}$.

Comment: You're forgetting to apply the chain rule...

Comment: *This **seems** so wrong* - Well, appearances can be quite deceiving. :-)

Comment: Actually, it is $\frac{1}{4x}*4$

Comment: you can take 4 as a constant and take it outside if it helps

Answer (score 7):

$\ln(4x)=\ln 4 + \ln x$
and $d(\ln 4)/dx=0$
since it is a constant.

Answer (score 6):

By the chain rule, we have

$$\frac{d}{dx}\left(\ln(f(x))\right) = \frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}$$

In your case, $f(x) = 4x$. So, $$\frac{d}{dx}\left(\ln(4x)\right) = \dfrac{(4x)'}{4x} = \dfrac 4{4x} = \frac 1x$$

Comment: I added a $d/dx$ where I think you missed one out.

Comment: Yes, indeed. Thanks @Ben for catching my oversight!

Answer (score 3):

$$\frac{d(\ln4x)}{dx}=\frac{d(\ln4x)}{d(4x)}\cdot\frac{d(4x)}{dx}=\frac1{4x}\cdot4$$

Or, $$\ln4x=\ln4+\ln x\implies\frac{d(\ln4x)}{dx}=\cdots$$

Answer (score 3):

All answers so far (added later: except Marty Cohen's) have (correctly) pointed out that you need to use the chain rule. Here is another reason why you should not be surprised by the outcome. If $c$ is a constant, and $f$ is a differentiable function, the $(c +f(x))^{\prime} = f^{\prime}(x),$ that is $c+f(x)$ and $f(x)$ have the same derivative everywhere. Notice that $\ln(4x) = \ln(4) +\ln(x)$, and $\ln(4)$ is just a constant, so the derivative of $\ln(4x)$ should indeed be the same as the derivative of $\ln(x)$ wherever either derivative exists.

Comment: Oops: I missed Marty Cohen's answer, which gives the same reason

Comment: And you missed that @lab was the first to make that point (second half of post, following "or"...)

Comment: @lab: Sorry for that too.